# Could you give me some general advice on .NET and TLS 1.2

Tags: .net, ssl

I've searched other responses and the solution that worked for me was to insert

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

before calling the services that failed.

However, I'm left with these questions.

1. Does this only change the default protocol for that particular application ?
2. Since most (all ?) services now appear to require the upgrade, why would a Windows update not have changed the default ?
3. Why would libraries supplied by the developers of the services not have included this in their code, since the service requires it ?
4. It took me a long time to discover the source of my problem since the error messages from my application - from Microsoft code - only gave a very general error.  What should I have been reading to tell me that upgrading to TLS 1.2 was not something provided by a Windows update ?  I spent a lot of time thinking it was a firewall problem ....
5. So is the best advice to include the code above at the start of every one of my applications, (just in case !! ) ?

Answer (score 2):

TLS 1.2 is a default protocol in .NET Framework 4.6.2 onwards.

If you ensure that your application is running with a target framework of 4.6.2 or greater then there should be no need to include that line of code.

When I've experienced this issue, I've also had to ensure that the `<httpRuntime>` node in Web.config explicitly states the target framework (e.g. `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />`)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this only change the default protocol for that particular application ?

Correct.

> Since most (all ?) services now appear to require the upgrade, why would a Windows update not have changed the default ?

It is technically a breaking change, thus opting old versions of Frameworks into new TLS configuration was not done via Windows Update. Instead, it is done by the framework version.

It could break in some circumstances where a server that supports TLS 1.0 would incorrectly handle a client that offered TLS 1.2, even though the server could negotiate 1.0.

[The TLS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) from Microsoft recommend different ways of handling versions of frameworks.

> Why would libraries supplied by the developers of the services not have included this in their code, since the service requires it ?

TLS on .NET Framework depends on the version of Windows as well. A client  library could not reasonably force a particular version of TLS unless they shipped their own TLS implementation as well.

> What should I have been reading to tell me that upgrading to TLS 1.2 was not something provided by a Windows update

That is unfortunate - the guide I mentioned previously is helpful for understand the issue and different ways to remediate it. Hopefully in the future the errors and configuration will be more clear.